# not getting output in group by using linq query

Tags: linq

My table is:

```
Student_answer_Master:

Stud_ans_id       QuestionId    OptionId     iscorrect
1                    25              1          1

2                    26              1          0

3                    27              2          1

4                    27              3          1

5                    27              4          1

6                    28              1          1

8                    29              1          0

9                    29              2          1

10                   29              3          1
```

(my options are single choice and multiple choice(checkbox)).

now what i want to get total count of only those question which are correct.

1-indicate correct

0-indicate incorrect.

i want output:**3**(for **questionid 25,27,28**)

this is my linq query:

```
 var data = (from temp in context.Student_Answer_Master
                        where temp.isCorrect == '1'
                        group temp by temp.Question_Id into g
                        select new {g.Key}).Count();
```

but here count is coming 0.

can any one tell me what is wrong with my query???

Comment: maybe you don't want to check equality with 'char' ? try with "string"

Comment: or maybe I didn't understood your question... I can't understand how can Question 29 be correct for option 2 and 3 too...

Comment: bro dont see optionid field bcoz for dat i am having asnwermaster where my asnwer are stored and by comparision i have calculated this iscorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this this should work.

```
 var data = (from temp in s
                       group temp by temp.Question_Id into g
                       select new { questionid = g.Key, minIscorrect = g.Min(x => x.isCorrect) }).Where(y => y.minIscorrect != 0).Count();
```

There are 2 things that looks wrong to me in your Query.

- comparing an int to a char temp.isCorrect == '1' if you make it temp.isCorrect == 1, you will still get 4 as the count because you are eliminating the row that has wrong answer for Question id 29.
- once you get the group, you need to check if there are any wrong answers for the question 
  if yes eliminate that and then put a count

Comment: thank u so much.ur solution works.thank u once again